# /etc/profile, /etc/bash.basrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc are not read

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, bashrc

I am a running "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS" Linux.

I've installed/upgrade some packages, but i do not remember exactly which packages.

Since this operation, i have lost ls coloration for all users and PS1 environnement variable (except root user).

I have added some echo in this files:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.basrc
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

They are not read when i am connecting from ssh.

Please note i have tried to create new users. It does not change anything...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually running bash?

Comment: Yes i am running bash in all cases